# Points in general position form convex polygon

Tags: discrete-geometry

Find an upper bound for n points if these n points in general position form empty  convex pentagon 
I don't understand the meaning

Comment: It's a bit vague, yes. "Points in general position" typically means that no three of them are on the same line. I'm not quite sure what they mean by "these $n$ points form empty convex pentagon".

Comment: Is this intended to be a specific case of the [happy ending problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_ending_problem)? How many points are required to guarantee that five of them can be chosen which form a convex pentagon?